# How to fix the bone influencing other meshes

Tags: bones

I have boned a laptop and when I moved the bone for the screen, it goes fine, but a vertice on the laptop goes up or down all the time when i move the bone for the screen. How can I fix it though? I looked at it to see if there were any weight paint at that area but no.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit* mode, select the vertex, open the *N* panel, you'll see if the vertex is part of a vertex group it is not supposed to be part of, you can remove if from this group if you press the X button.

[image]

Blue doesn't mean the selected bone or group has no influence on these vertices, it might be a very low influence, to check the real zero influence in *Weight Paint* mode you need to display the *Zero Weight* option of the *Viewport Overlays*.

[image]